# C# Func<> - looking for an explanation - not a solution

Tags: c#

i am using 
Math.net, among other methods i use integration, the integration function i use is defined as foloows:

```
public static double IntegrateComposite(
  Func<double, double> f,
  double intervalBegin,
  double intervalEnd,
  int numberOfPartitions)
```

yet, my call syntax is:

```
p = IntegrateComposite(
tau => MyFunction(r, tau, appCfg, Ta, Da) * ProbDensity(tau), 
lowLim, hiLim,  32)
```

My function is better defined as `Func<double, double, double, double, double, double>` and not the above `Func<double, double>`, still everything works fine
Why?

Comment: By "everything works fine" are you getting the same results? Or do you mean no compiler errors?

Comment: thanks for all the good folks who bothered to answer, it WAS helpful, i know that the only 'real' argument i pass is Tau, the notion of 'Closure' and the usage idea of 'captures parameters' made a clearer division between the actual parameter and the 'supporting roles/variables'
once again - thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is your the function you pass in, the only input argument is tau.

```
tau => MyFunction(r, tau, appCfg, Ta, Da) * ProbDensity(tau)
```

The other varibales `r, appCfg, Ta, Da` are 'closed over' by a [closure](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

`Func<double, double>` means

> a function which takes 1 argument of type double in, and returns double

That's exactly what your arrow function does, no matter how many external variables are involved into calculation.

Answer (score 1):

`Func<T1, T2, T3..., T(n), TResult>` is a type that represents a method which takes (n) number of parameters with specified types (could be 0), and returns an object of type `TResult`.

By `Func<double, double>`, it specifies that it must be a method which takes one `double` as a parameter and return a `double`.

In this example, Lambda function is used (which also can be represented by Func).

```cs
tau => {return MyFunction(r, tau, appCfg, Ta, Da) * ProbDensity(tau)},
```

The only parameter you pass into the lambda function is `tau`, which can be seen on the left hand side of the arrow. Other variables such as `r`, `tau`, `appCfg`... are captured variables.

Another example of generic delegates:
`(obj, e) => {Console.WriteLine(obj)}` is passed two variables named `obj` and `e`. Unlike your example, It returns nothing. This is represented as `Action<T1, T2>` which represents a method that returns nothing.